# Quotient of cumulative binomial distribution functions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Given to integers $n < m \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and a probability $p$, I'm struggling to calculate (or at least get an upper bound for) the quotient
$$Q = \frac{F(n+1;m,p)}{F(n;m,p)}$$
where $F$ denotes the cumulative binomial distribution function, i.e.
$$F(n;m,p) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} \text{.}$$
Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!